# How do I set presentation-heading-font to "Source Serif 4" in .scss file?

Tags: sass, quarto, reveal.js

I'm trying to create a custom revealjs theme to use with Quarto. I really want to use Source Serif 4 as the presentation heading font with Roboto in the body, but I'm struggling to get it to render.

```
/*-- scss:defaults --*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital@0;1&display=swap');

// fonts
$font-family-sans-serif: "Roboto", sans-serif !default;

// headings
$presentation-heading-font: "Source Serif 4", serif !default;
```

With this, the presentation heading font renders as Roboto. Curiously, if I switch the two fonts so that the heading is Roboto and font family is Source Serif 4 as shown below, everything renders as expected.

```
/*-- scss:defaults --*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital@0;1&display=swap');

// fonts
$font-family-sans-serif: "Source Serif 4", serif !default;

// headings
$presentation-heading-font: "Roboto", sans-serif !default;
```

Also, if I omit `$presentation-heading-font` and set the font family to Source Serif 4, the headings are in Source Serif 4.

What am I missing? How do I set presentation-heading-font to "Source Serif 4"?